# How to store data inside session array in given format?

Tags: php, session

```
Category Name
  List A = Rm 20
  List B = Rm 50

Category Name
  List A = Rm 40

category Name
  List A = Rm 80
  List B = Rm 40
  List C = Rm 25
```

I tried

```
$_SESSION['info']=array('category'=>$category,'list'=>$list,'rate'=>$rate);
```

But it doesn't display as the format wanted. Can anyone help please?`

EDIT:

I think I didn't elaborate clearly.

The values for item category, list and rate come from user input.

SO I store them in variables like this:

php

```
$category[]=$_POST['category'];<br/>
$list[]=$_POST['list'];
$rate[]=$_POST['rate'];
```

storing in session array like this:

```
$_SESSION['info']]=array('level'=>$level,'subject'=>$subject2,'rate'=>$rate2);`
```

html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category['category name']" id="category" class=category" value="1">

<input type="checkbox" name="list['category name']" id="list" value="'List id'">

<input type="textbox" name="rate['List name']" class="rate" value="" id="'List Name'">
```

Comment: Try `$_SESSION['Category Name']['List A'] = "Rm 20"` and so on.

Comment: @Maximus2012, could you give sample please, I don't get you. Did you mena this: $_SESSION['info'][$level][$subject]=array($rate2);

Comment: Don't use `Array()` on right side. Just assign the value. `$_SESSION['info'][$level][$subject]=$rate2;`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$_SESSION['info'] = Array(
    'Category Name' => Array(
        'List A' => 'Rm 20', // don't forget "," if you're adding additional item.
        'List B' => 'Rm 50'
    ), 
    'Category Name' => Array(
        'List A' => 'Rm 40'
    )
    // Etc..
);
```

Comment: I edited  my question,can you help me to format using variables where each is array please?